# Message handlers don't always receive messages posted via http inbound endpoint

Tags: spring-integration

I have a configuration for a process that receives receipts and also mails the receipts to a number of recipients in a mailing list. All receipts received are saved to a database. In addition all mail sent to the recipients are saved to a database for report generation. When the messages are received they are transformed by a transformer and a recipient-list-router sends the messages to both the respective JMS queues for the receipts and mailing queues. The goal is to have them processed concurrently and independently of each other. However, when testing using a browser, the messages are not always processed by the respective handlers registered with the queues. The behavior is rather unpredictable. Here is my configuration:

```
    <!--Queues and ConnectionFactory Configurations -->

    <import resource="queue.definitions.xml" />


    <int:channel id="requestChannel">

    </int:channel>

    <int:channel id="queue1" />

    <int:channel id="queue2" />




    <int-http:inbound-channel-adapter id="inboundRequests"
        supported-methods="PUT,POST" status-code-expression=
                       "T(org.springframework.http.HttpStatus).ACCEPTED"
        path="/receipts" channel="requestChannel">
    </int-http:inbound-channel-adapter>






    <int:chain input-channel="requestChannel">
        <int:transformer ref="receiptTransformer" />
        <int:recipient-list-router>
            <int:recipient channel="queue2" />
            <int:recipient channel="queue1" />
        </int:recipient-list-router>
    </int:chain>




        <int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="receipt.outbound.channel"
            channel="queue1" destination="receiptsQueue" />

        <int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="mail.outbound.channel"
            channel="queue2" destination="mailingQueue" />

        class="org.springframework.jms.listener.
                              adapter.MessageListenerAdapter">
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean
                    class="com.express.ccs.MailProcessingDelegate" />

        <bean id="mailingQueueListener"
                            </constructor-arg>
            <property name="defaultListenerMethod" value="receiveMessage" />
            <property name="messageConverter">
                <null />
            </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="receiptsProcessingListener"
            class="org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter
            .MessageListenerAdapter">
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="com.express.ccs.ReceiptsProcessingDelegate" />
            </constructor-arg>
            <property name="defaultListenerMethod" value="receiveMessage" />
            <property name="messageConverter">
                <null />
            </property>
        </bean>
        <bean id="mailingQueueContainer"
            class="org.springframework.jms.listener.
           DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
            <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
            <property name="destination" ref="mailingQueue" />
            <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1" />
            <property name="messageListener" ref="mailingQueueListener" />
        </bean>

          <bean id="receiptJmsContainer"
            class="org.springframework.jms.listener.
            DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
            <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
            <property name="destination" ref="receiptsQueue" />
            <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1" />
            <property name="messageListener"      
                   ref="receiptsProcessingListener" />
          </bean>
       </beans>
```

ReceiptsProcessingDelegates receives the post from the browser rest client sometimes and not at other times. The same is true for the MailProcessingDelegate. As a result the mailing and receipt information are not always sent to the database.  What is wrong with my configuration? I would really appreciate help in fixing this configuration.

Comment: I suggest turning on DEBUG logging and follow the messages through the flows.

Comment: Does the configuration look right to you?

Comment: On the face of it, yes, but it's not so easy to debug static configuration, just by looking at it; DEBUG logs are always your friend.

Comment: Thank you, I have turned on debugging and also created a file appender to find out what's going on. I just wanted to first of all make sure my configuration looked right